# iOS Simulator known issues

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios-simulator

I have both provisioned devices set up to be built to by XCode and the built-in iOS simulator. In general I like to do quick bug-fixes and early-stage testing in the simulator because it tends to be able to do multiple runs more quickly.

**Does anyone know of a resource that lists known issues with the simulator?** By "known issues" I mean situations where the simulator's behavior deviates significantly from that of the device. Sometimes I won't know if something is a genuine bug or just a simulator problem and it's kind of a pain to run on a testing device just to verify.

Comment: http://openradar.appspot.com/page/1

Comment: My guess is that if a definitive list exists, it would be on Apple's side, available only the members of their developer program, and covered by NDA of some sort.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've never seen anything like that in the developer program, but I'll take a quick look. -edit- Searched the developer library, only 2 items with simulator in the name. One on a specific issue, the other on testing bluetooth.

Comment: Unless apple has published such a list, I wouldn't trust any others and just bite the bullet.